# Rstudio can't display outputs properly

Tags: windows, r, rstudio

After fresh installation of win7, R and Rstudio, I found it can't display properly the R outputs as shown in the attached screenshoot. I have Win7 (English version) and set Chinese for non-Unicode programs. How to solve this problem? Thx

[image]

Comment: @KLDavenport Thx. But I think it just can't help with mine here. I actually tried the same commands, e.g. library("copula"), in the naive R and it works as it should do. The above issue is only happened with Rstudio.

Comment: You might want to compare the outputs of `sessionInfo()` and `Sys.getenv()` in both vanilla R and in RStudio.

Comment: Check your versions of R and Rstudio, copula package requires R (≥ 2.15.2).
This warning message means that you should install the latest version of R which is 3.0.1. Copula package is build under this latest version.

Comment: @Dason the outputs of seesionInfo() show: R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252

Comment: @itfeature.com I have R 3.0.0 installed. The issue is that the warning message in Rstudio contains non-English characters which is very annoying. I also tried library("tseries") in Rstudio and got the same problem. But when I tried them in R, it was ok. Odd.

Comment: @onethird: the current version of R is 3.0.1. for other package is you are getting same type of error then there is problem of local language error. Means that user profile path to R directory is still for english language.

Comment: @itfeature.com I think it is the local language error. How to set the local language of Rstudio be English?

Comment: Rstudio depends on regional and language setting of your computer. From control panel check region and language tool to set language.